# MFC hangs while loading if dllimport function called

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, dll, mfc, loading

I have an MFC application, "Analyser", which uses a Dll with resources.

There is a function to get an instance of the Dialog contained in the dll called GetCriteriaDlg.

*My dll file:*

```
extern "C" {__declspec(dllexport) CCriteriaDlg* GetCriteriaDlg(void );}

in the dll cpp file I have

    extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) CCriteriaDlg* GetCriteriaDlg(void )
    {
        return &dlg;
    }
}
```

*My AnalyserDoc.cpp where I use the function:*

```
extern "C" {__declspec(dllimport) CCriteriaDlg* GetCriteriaDlg(void );}
```

there is also a class eported in the dll

```
class AFX_EXT_CLASS CCriteriaDlg : public CDialog
```

And their is an exact duplicate of the exported class header file included in *AnalyserDoc.cpp* under the name *DllImports.h*

*AnalyserDoc.cpp* has a function which is mapped to a menu item

```
Void CAnalyserDoc::OnAnalyseRun()
{
    // TODO: Add your command handler code here
    CCriteriaDlg *dlg=GetCriteriaDlg();
    dlg->DoModal();
}
```

Now here's where it gets wierd. If I have everything as is the Program starts but the usual SD window of the MFC never appears and I have to end process from the task manager.

But if I was to comment out the content of `OnAnalyseRun()` then the window loads fine(but obviously then their is no action to on the method call, I tried swapping things around and if I declare *dlg only without the method call the window loads fine so I think it definitely has something to do with `GetCriteriaDlg()`.

Why is it happening?

Comment: But you didn't try to call `GetCriteriaDlg` without calling `DoModal`, did ya?

Comment: Yeah I tried that too, adding in the DoModal bit was a recent addition.

Comment: Did you try to debug this program?

Comment: I think GetCriteriaDlg returns a pointer to a dialog which hasn't initialized propertly.

Comment: Ok Actually scratch that, now even with all code removed from 'OnAnalyseRun' the document window still never appears even though the program is running.

Comment: Try and move `CCriteriaDlg *dlg=GetCriteriaDlg();` somewhere globally. Then in the menu event just do `dlg->DoModal();`

Comment: But that's the thing the program window doesn't even appear for me to get to the menu to click on Analyse>Run

Comment: @vulkanino Tried moving the method call into another method but still had the same problem.

The problem occurs only when the solution has been built with the method call to 'GetCriteriaDlg()'. If I Clean and Rebuild after removing the method call then it returns to opening the application window.